# Write to a file until it reaches a certain size, then start new file

Tags: python, bash

I am using the command line tool [twarc](https://github.com/DocNow/twarc) to download Twitter data as a csv. I have set up my twarc commands and they successfully execute on the command line without issue. Example command:

`twarc dosomething > outputfile.jsonl`

While I would like to carry out a collection process over an extended period of time, the output files become a bit too large (10+GB) after running for more than a day.

I would like to run a bash script that executes the twarc command, runs until the output file reaches a certain limit, and then starts a new file.

These questions are related...

- [When file reaches certain size add data to new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739416/when-file-reaches-certain-size-add-data-to-new-file)
- [Write to a file until it reaches a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511936/write-to-a-file-until-it-reaches-a-certain-size)

...although I've had little luck with the translation.

Could anyone provide some insight on setting up a basic bash script to execute a command, wait until a file grows to X size, and then start again on a new file? Could take it from there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is aptly named `split`:

```
twarc dosomething | split -b 10G
```

You can also do this by line count if you want to avoid lines being split between files, though you lose the ability to specify size:

```
twarc dosomething | split -l 10000000
```

Comment: Wow - thank you SO much! Although the question didn't meet SO guidelines, I think this is an important tool for people in similar situations. Thanks again, really appreciate it!

Comment: For those who find this useful, note that you should NOT write the command to a file as I do in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Another tool is [`logrotate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html).

It normally runs on schedule from `cron` and in its config file you specify what log files to split, how, when, archive, mail and how much history to keep.

The benefit of `logrotate` is that your applications don't need to implement any log rotation policy at all. They just need to write the log into a file or `stdout` redirected into a file.